# Calculating the Savitzky Golay Coefficients

Tags: algorithms, signal-processing

I am working on a [signal-smoothing algorithm](http://www.chem.uoa.gr/applets/appletsmooth/appl_smooth2.html) for personal interest. I understand the basic concept of the Savitzky-Golay algorithm but I would like to understand how the [coefficients](http://www.statistics4u.info/fundstat_eng/cc_savgol_coeff.html) were discovered. Can someone please explain the the mathematics behind it, so I could calculate the coefficients on my own?

How would the matrix look? For example [here](http://www.statistics4u.com/fundstat_eng/cc_filter_savgol_math.html) states: "For n=5 and p=3, the filtering coefficients are b= [-0.0857 0.3429 0.4857 0.3429 -0.0857]." However, it does not show the steps to achieve this. If n equal the number of points to sample and p equals the power of the polynomial.

- [Least Squares Tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8mAZYv5wIcE)
- [Applying Least Squares](http://www.vias.org/tmdatanaleng/cc_filter_savgol_math.html)

Comment: A description  and routine is given in Numerical Recipes:  http://www.fizyka.umk.pl/nrbook/c14-8.pdf

Comment: There's a better derivation in Hildebrand; read the whole chapter on polynomial fitting first so you can understand how the smoothing coefficients are calculated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was supposed to be a comment, but it got too long.

I'm personally not too enamored of the NR routine for Savitzky-Golay myself; it has to use Gaussian elimination (and thus a two-dimensional array) for what I think is a well-structured problem. Peter Gorry's proposal in [this paper](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ac00205a007) is a better choice, IMHO (a proper implementation merely requires a few one-dimensional arrays; see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/87049) for a *Mathematica* implementation). In any event, looking at the [original article](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ac60214a047) by Savitzky and Golay should help you a great deal, as well as F.B. Hildebrand's [*Introduction to Numerical Analysis*](http://books.google.com/books?id=hqucruPBheQC); Hildebrand does not explicitly refer to the Savitzky-Golay coefficients, but he gives the [general idea](http://books.google.com/books?id=hqucruPBheQC&pg=PA357) of using least-squares fit polynomials for smoothing data.

Comment: If I understand correctly would I be able to say that Savitzky-Golay's algorithm is a least squares of polynomials applied with the framing of moving average?

Comment: Secondly does the least square have to be applied to each frame or can coefficients be calculated based upon the number of elements you want to frame?

Comment: @Shiftbit: Well, the underlying assumption is that the data are equispaced (if your data is sampled at regular intervals, then this assumption is satisfied). You can think of it as a more elaborate version of the moving average, except that the weights are chosen such that it is as if you performed a least-squares polynomial fit in each window, but done more efficiently.

Comment: As a matter of fact, if you won't be varying the window size and polynomial degree, you don't even need to supply a Savitzky-Golay routine; you can just use it to compute the needed coefficients for the window just once, store those coefficients in an array, and convolve as you please.